# AsyncTask does work on Samsung S3, but not HTC Desire

Tags: android

I have a class which extends AsyncTask:

```
package Logic;


public class ReadConfig extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {

 ProgressBar progressBar;
 Context context;
 URL url;
 FileInputStream config;
 static CreateApplicationFolder folders;
 File file;
 DocumentBuilderFactory dbf;
 DocumentBuilder db;
 Document doc;

 SharedPreferences prefs;
 File configFile;

 public ReadConfig(Context context, ProgressBar progressBar)
        throws ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, IOException {

    this.context = context;
    this.progressBar = progressBar;

    folders = new CreateApplicationFolder(context);
    dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
    configFile = new File(folders.getPathToNode() + "/config.xml");

    prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
}

protected void onPreExecute() {

    progressBar.incrementProgressBy(1);

}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    android.os.Debug.waitForDebugger();
    int i;

    if (!configFile.exists()) {
        sleep();
        return "noConfig";
    } else {
        try {
            doc = db.parse(configFile);
        } catch (SAXException e2) {
            Log.e("SAX: ", e2.getMessage());
        } catch (IOException e2) {
            Log.e("IO: ", e2.getMessage());
        }
        doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

        Log.i("ROOT NODE: ", doc.getDocumentElement().getNodeName());

        NodeList listOfMail = doc.getElementsByTagName("mail");

        int totalMail = listOfMail.getLength();
        Log.i("LENGTH: ", Integer.toString(totalMail));

        for (i = 0; i < totalMail; i++) {

            Node firstMailSetting = listOfMail.item(i);
            Element e = (Element) firstMailSetting;

            if (i == 0) {

                putSharedPrefs("host", getTagValue("host", e));
                putSharedPrefs("mail", getTagValue("account", e));
                putSharedPrefs("port", getTagValue("port", e));
                putSharedPrefs("pw", getTagValue("password", e));
            } else if (i == 1) {
                putSharedPrefs("supportMail", getTagValue("account", e));
            } else if (i == 2) {
                putSharedPrefs("Tomail", getTagValue("account", e));
            }
            sleep();

        }
    }

    return "";
}

protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

    if (result.equals("noConfig")) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "No Config file was found..",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Intent mainIntent = new Intent(context, MAIN.class);
        context.startActivity(mainIntent);
    } else {
        Intent mainIntent = new Intent(context, MAIN.class);
        context.startActivity(mainIntent);
    }
}

private String getTagValue(String sTag, Element eElement) {
    try {
        NodeList nlList = eElement.getElementsByTagName(sTag).item(0)
                .getChildNodes();
        Node nValue = (Node) nlList.item(0);
        return nValue.getNodeValue();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return "";
    }

}

public void putSharedPrefs(String tag, String value) {
    SharedPreferences.Editor prefEditor = prefs.edit();
    prefEditor.putString(tag, value);
    prefEditor.commit();
}

public void sleep() {
    for (int j = 0; j < 1; j++) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

}

The "Problem" occuers in the following line of code:

```
if (!configFile.exists()) {
        sleep();
        return "noConfig";
```

This will return "noConfig" to the `onPostExecute` method, which should show a `Toast`:

```
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

    if (result.equals("noConfig")) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "No Config file was found..",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Intent mainIntent = new Intent(context, MAIN.class);
        context.startActivity(mainIntent);
    } else {
        Intent mainIntent = new Intent(context, MAIN.class);
        context.startActivity(mainIntent);
    }
}
```

This code works on the Samsung S3, but when I test it on a HTC desire the screen turns black and the `Toast` just keeping showing all the time without starting the new `Activity`. No errors, no exceptions what so ever. Any ideas?

**EDIT**

The AsyncTask is being called from my splash screen:

```
try {
        new ReadConfig(Splash.this, pd).execute("");
    } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
        Log.e("Parser: ", e.getMessage());
    } catch (SAXException e) {
        Log.e("Sax: ", e.getMessage());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("IO: ", e.getMessage()); 
    }
```

The `pd` object is a `ProgressDialog` from my `Layout`, beneath is the basic flow:

Splashscreen init. some settings from the xml file which is parsed in the `doInBackground` Method. If the config file doesn't exist, just toast a message about that and start the Main Activity.

Comment: Are you sure this code works in Samsung S3??? because in your start Activity code I didn't see any Activity name.. and what referring `this.class`?

Comment: I just removed the class name.

Comment: When you say `the Toast just keeping showing all the time` it means that the toast is still, or keeps coming and coming... In that case, could you add some log to track how many times `onPostExecute` is called ?

Answer (score 0):

In your line

```
new Intent(context, this.class);
```

this.class is representing your ReadConfig class which is **not** an Activity, which is weird. Did you get this code out from your activity (where it could have been an inner class ?)

You should try to change `this.class` to `WhateverActivity.class`

Comment: I just removed the class name, this has nothing to do with the problem. I can see why you got confused.

Comment: Ok. Then from where is called your ReadConfig ? If it's from MAIN.onCreate, then maybe that your activity does not have enough time to startup before being launched again. It's a little rude to start the entiere activity when (I think) you just want to start over your ReadConfig task.

Comment: Ok, but is your splash screen launched from MAIN activity ? :) I find it strange to start your activity again (in top of itself !)

Comment: No, my splash screen has the `intent-filter`:  `<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />` which indicates that this is the first class to be called when the app starts.

Answer (score 0):

Given the issue is to do with handsets, and handset manufacturers tend to change/tinker odd and sods i would look at:

Try removing:
android.os.Debug.waitForDebugger();

Also, do you need the sleep()

Focused on your specific issue of the activity not starting, i might try

```
Intent mainIntent = new Intent(context.getApplicationContext(), MAIN.class);
context.getApplicationContext().startActivity(mainIntent);
```

To remove any ambiguity about how it should handle starting the intent. You might also call a method from within your Activity to handle this, rather than from the Async Task.